# find and regex - find files with names starting with given name

Tags: find, regular-expression

I need a regex expression to use along with `find` to find all the files which name start with a given string, for example `proc`.

I tried with `find . -regex '^proc*'` but it gives me no results.

Comment: I have another regex expression which finds me all the files with certain extensions `.*\.(c|h|txt)`, and under one condition in my script I plan to join these two patterns together.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be better to use just the `-name 'proc*'` in this case, which uses globbing, and searches through the filename only (unlike `-regex` which searches through the whole directory entries leading to the filename).

If you insist on using `-regex`, leveraging greediness:

```
find . -type f -regex '.*/proc[^/]*$'
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `regex` flag

```
$ find . -type f -name "proc*"
```

Comment: The question is valid 'how to use -regex' answering with "don't" is not helpful.

Comment: @JayM
 OP is asking how to find files where name starts with a given string. This answer is just pointing out that he can achieve that without the need of using `regex` option.